# DOJO Movable Editor is not resizing until dragged

Tags: dojo

I have a DOJO Editor that is movable

```
<div id="dnd" dojoType="dojo.dnd.Moveable">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Editor" height="120px" width="250px"
            id="editor3"
            data-dojo-props="plugins:['bold','italic']">
            <p>This instance is created with customized toolbar/ plugins</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to know :
1- why changing the width attribute does not make any difference in the Editor's width
2- why the Editor resizes itself only when dragged for the first time(to the appropiate height)

I use DOJO 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the style attribute on the div and not height and width and dojo will honor that.

```
<div id="editor3"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/Editor" style="width:250px;"
    data-dojo-props="plugins:['bold','italic'], height: '120px'">
        <p>This instance is created with customized toolbar/ plugins</p>
</div>
```

The height will be auto-determined (be as small as possible and expand as required), but there is a minHeight property and a height property (shown above) you can assign in your data-dojo-props if you require height control